How do I animate the angle_end of Kivy's Line instruction
I am trying to animate a Line's angle_end from 0 to 180 degrees
using Kivy and Python but I'm running into an AttributeError.
What am I doing wrong?
Here's my Python code:
def trying_something(self, *args):
    my_circle = self.ids.my_other_canvas.canvas.get_group("b")[0]

    anim = Animation( 
        my_circle.circle[-1] + 180,
        # end_angle = 180,
        d = 2,)

    anim.start(my_circle)

And here's my Kivy code:

<MyOtherWidget@Widget>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 0, 0

    canvas:
        Color:
            group: "a"
            rgba: get_color_from_hex("808080")

        Line:
            group: "b"
            circle: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            width: dp(5)
            
<MyScreen>:
    # some code

    MDCard:
        # some code
                
        MDBoxLayout:
            # some code

            MyOtherWidget:
                id: my_other_canvas


